# Understanding Ruby and Sinatra syntax

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a need to decipher some Ruby code. Being a Python dev, I am having hard time making sense to some of the syntax.

I need to deal with some (mostly clean and readable) Sinatra code. I started with a [Sinatra tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/singing-with-sinatra--net-18965), and it looks something like this:

```
get '/' do
    "Hello, World!"
end
```

Now, I know that in Ruby you don't need parentheses to call a function. So if I were to try to understand the above, I would say:

1. `get` is a function that takes as its first argument the route.
2. `'/'` is the first argument
3. `do ... end` block is an anonymous function

Please correct me if I am wrong above, and explain in detail anything I might be missing.

Also they say that Sinatra is a DSL -- does this mean that it is parsing some special syntax that is not official Ruby?

Comment: You're correct on points 1–3 (although a Ruby block isn't an anonymous function *per se*, it's not all that different). Sinatra is a DSL, but no it doesn't use any non-Ruby syntax.

Answer (score 3):

`do ... end` (or `{ ... }`) is a *block*, a very important concept in Ruby. It was noticed that very often functions that take other functions as parameter (`map`, `filter`, `grep`, `timeout`...) very often accept a single function. So the Ruby designer decided to make a special syntax for it.

It is often said that in Ruby, everything is an object. This is not quite true: code is not an object. Code can be *wrapped* into an object. But Ruby blocks are pure code - not an object, not a first-order value at all. Blocks are a piece of code associated with a function call.

Your code snippet is equivalent to this:

```
self.get('/') do
    return "Hello, World!"
end
```

The `get` method takes one parameter and a block; *not* two parameters. In a hypothetical example where `get` did take two parameters, we would have to write something like this:

```
get('/', lambda { "Hello, World" })
```

or

```
get('/', Proc.new { "Hello, World" })
```

but notice that the way we wrap code into objects involves calling methods `lambda` and `Proc.new` - and giving them a block (and zero parameters)!

There are many tutorials on "Ruby blocks", so I will not link any particular one.

Because of the block syntax, Ruby is very good at making dialects (still fully syntactic Ruby) that express certain concepts very neatly. Sinatra uses the `get...` "syntax" (but actually just a method call) to describe a web server; Rake uses `task...` "syntax" to describe build processes; `RSpec`, a testing framework, has its own DSL (that is still Ruby) that describes desired behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

After some reading, I understood the code blocks.

Ruby code blocks are simple. They are 'closures'. There's two ways to write a block

```
do |x|
  do_something(x)
end

{|x| do_something(x) }
```

The `|x|` is the argument that gets passed to the code within the block.

The crucial bit to grasping code blocks is to understand how they are used with methods.

In Ruby, methods are a bit different.

- In addition to arguments, ***any method can accept a code block.***
- Code blocks are NOT arguments, but they are a separate entity that can be passed to a method along with arguments
- A method can choose not to call the code block, in which case, any code block that was passed is ignored
- If a method calls a code block, then it is necessary to pass it when calling the method, or otherwise Ruby will complain.
- `yield` within a method executes the code block

For more on code blocks read this: http://mixandgo.com/blog/mastering-ruby-blocks-in-less-than-5-minutes

Comment: Nice answer, glad you got some insight. Ruby blocks are not closures though, but they *can* be. See [this chat](http://www.artima.com/intv/closures.html) with Matz (the creator of Ruby) and [this helpful article](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) to get the nuances behind blocks, procs and lambdas.